# Yii2 - ActiveForm and afterValidate events

Tags: php, yii2

I am using ActiveForm with the `afterValidate()` event, however currently the `afterValidate()` gets triggered on any validation event. How can I differentiate between the events `validateOnSubmit`, `validateOnBlur` and `validateOnChange`?

Basically, I only want my `afterValidate()` function to get triggered on submit. Here is my code:

PHP:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'register-form',
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'validate-form',
    ],
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
    'validateOnBlur' => true,
    'validateOnChange' => true,
]); ?>
```

JS:

```
// JS afterValidate function
$('.validate-form').on('afterValidate', function (event, messages, errorAttributes) {
    $('.error-popup').show();

    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="error-popup">Please review the errors in the form below.</div>
```

As you can see in my `afterValidate()` function above, an error popup is shown if there are validation errors. However I only want this to error popup to appear if there are any validation errors when the user submits the form.

If there is a validation error on blur/change then the normal inline validation should occur without any error popup.

From my understanding, `beforeSubmit` event is only triggered when validation has passed.

Comment: doe this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882535/yii2-disable-activeform-ajax-validation-on-field-blur/49886118#49886118

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam nope. The thing I still want validation to happen on blur and on change, but I also want to trigger some custom JS on submit.

Comment: @GSTAR `beforeSubmit` is the frontend call you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35199613/1143731

Comment: @GSTAR after validate will be triggered after every validate call, why arent you using the `beforeSubmit` event

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I have edited the question to provide more context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yii's active form JS save some info into `yiiActiveForm` data property. There is `submitting` property that you can use to determine if the form is in validation before form submission.

```js
$('.validate-form').on('afterValidate', function (event, messages, errorAttributes) {
    let data = $('.validate-form').data('yiiActiveForm');
    //check if we are in submission process and if there are any errors
    if (data.submitting && errorAttributes.length > 0) {
        $('.error-popup').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this the following way:

```
$("#register-form").on("beforeSubmit", function(event){
    $(this).yiiActiveForm('validateAttribute', 'contactform-phone');
    $(this).yiiActiveForm('validateAttribute', 'contactform-email');
    if ($(this).find('.has-error').length) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    return false;
});
```

The submit button triggers `beforeSubmit` event which in turn triggers validation of whichever fields you need. If validation results in error, you can do your JS logic associated with displaying error messages.

Comment: That's not going to work. The yii's `beforeSubmit` is only triggered when the form passes validation and it's going to be submitted. But OP needs to run his code when there are validation errors.

Comment: As the form is filled, it is validated when the input field loses focus, so by the time the user gets to the Submit button, the validation results are already in. Unless, I guess, the user simply submits an empty form...

This does work in a use-case for roughly the same scenario as described by the OP.

Comment: You are right that the validation results are already in but the problem is that when there are some validation errors the `beforeSubmit` event is not triggered. So your code will only be executed when there is no validation error.

Answer (score 0):

You should find has-error class after afterValidate and show popup try the following code

```
$('.validate-form').on('afterValidate', function (event, messages, errorAttributes) {
        if ($('.validate-form').find('.has-error').length) {
            $('.error-popup').show();
        }
  });
```